# Vuejs1: How can I encode a Vuejs argument string in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I'm trying to escape a single quote `'` in a string to be passed as argument to a component method function call.

In my template I'm printing (using php function `htmlentities` with `ENT_QUOTES`) something like:

```
  <button 
  @click.prevent="test('own&#039;s')">
     Test
  </button>
```

But seems that the html entity breaks vuejs parsing.

Here is the fiddle demo https://jsfiddle.net/76ueL3f8/1/

How can I securely escape the argument in php?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in Javascript, you escape quotes with a backtick. In the end, it has to look like this:

@click.prevent="test('own\'s')">

https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.addslashes.php

```
addSlashes("own's")
// should result in "own\'s"
```

Comment: The problem with addslashes is that  isn't completely safe to escape HTML attributes. In javascript you can escape using entity code of the single quote, but that doesn't work with vue.

Comment: To be clear addslashes has not protection for a double quote ("). Because even escaped the double quote closes the attribute.